# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 15002 ms [Android Studio]

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

Fresh Android Studio install. 
Running a Windows 10 64-bit - with the latest windows updates.
16 GBs of RAM.
Latest 1060 GTX drivers.
Android 9.0 and 10.0 tested. same error. 
All SDK tools fully updated to latest current versions.

[Error from event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajbS3.png)

[Virtual Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Npg.png)

[SDK Platforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmdaa.png)

[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyUI5.png)

I've tried:

1. Multiple Devices with different API levels 27 to 29
2. Changed Emulated Performance Between Software & Hardware
3. Switch Boot option between Quick and Cold boot
4. Checking and unchecking multi-core CPU (set at 4)
5. Set RAM to 4000 (overkill, i know); VM heap to 1000
6. Set RAM to 512
7. Changed resolution of device to 400x600

Nothing of the above worked.

Any help would be greately appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a whole day of looking stuff up on the internet i decided to checkout Windows features "Turn Windows Features ON/OFF" and had to enable Hyper V (see image below) and then restart my PC. Hope this saves you time and efforts. If not, there are a couple of others out there with this problem and a different solution. Good Luck!
[Hyper V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qlNx.png)